# Typecasting variables in jsp, using hyperlink

Tags: jsp, casting, hyperlink

I am creating a hyperlink in a JSP

```
<c:url var="viewweeklycertificationdetailsinquiry" value="/cwedetailsLink.do">
  <c:param name="forwardName" value="weeklycertificationdetailsinquiry" />
  <c:param name="cweId" value="${WorkSearchDetailsForm.cweID}" />
  <c:param name="claimId" value="${cininqform.claimId}" />
</c:url>

<tr>                                                                 
 <td>
  <html:link href="${viewweeklycertificationdetailsinquiry}">
     <bean:message key="access.cin.inq.monetary.view.weeklycertificationfilingdetails" />   
  </html:link>
 </td>  
</tr>
```

In `struts-config.xml`, the action name for the forward is: `weeklycertificationdetailsinquiryAction`.
In this action, in the `load()` method,

```
Long cweId = new Long(request.getParameter("cweId"));
Long claimId = new Long(request.getParameter("claimId"));
```

Now, when i click on the hyperlink, I am getting exceptions,

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:431)
    at java.lang.Long.<init>(Long.java:678)
    at gov.state.uim.cin.struts.inq.WeeklyCertificationDetailsInquiryAction.load(WeeklyCertificationDetailsInquiryAction.java:107)
    at gov.state.uim.framework.struts.CustomRequestProcessor.processLoadActionPerform(CustomRequestProcessor.java:681)
    at gov.state.uim.framework.struts.CustomRequestProcessor.processload(CustomRequestProcessor.java:610)
    at gov.state.uim.framework.struts.CustomRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(CustomRequestProcessor.java:518)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    at gov.state.uim.framework.struts.CustomActionServlet.process(CustomActionServlet.java:130)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
```

Do I have to typecast the variables in the JSP? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

will be raised when you pass a empty string or if the string you have passed to `Long` constructor is not parsable to long.

So, in your case the `cweId` and `claimId` may be null or empty. better use a condition to conform it, change to:

```
Long cweId = null;
Long claimId = null;

String cweIdStr = request.getParameter("cweId");
String claimIdStr = request.getParameter("cweId");

if(cweIdStr!=null && !cweIdStr.isEmpty())       
    cweId = new Long(cweIdStr);
if(claimIdStr!=null && !claimIdStr.isEmpty())
    claimId = new Long(claimIdStr);
```

---

See Also:

[Long(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#Long%28java.lang.String%29)

[ServletRequest#getParameter(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: By adding the check, it's ensured that no nullpointerexception will occur. I checked with typecasting, and that works. Anyway, thanks for your reply.